# Make a sound when hovering over a button in pygame

Tags: python, button, pygame

I'm trying to reproduce a sound everytime I hover over a button. This kind of works, but I want the sound to play only once (if i place my mouse over the button, the sound should play only one time. If i move the cursor in and out the button very quick, the sound should play a lot of times). This is my button class:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
splat = pygame.mixer.Sound("splat.ogg")

class Button():
    def __init__(self, image, pos, text_input, font, base_color, hovering_image):
        self.image = image
        self.image2 = image
        self.x_pos = pos[0]
        self.y_pos = pos[1]
        self.font = font
        self.base_color, self.hovering_image = base_color, hovering_image
        self.text_input = text_input
        self.text = self.font.render(self.text_input, True, self.base_color)
        if self.image is None:
            self.image = self.text
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.x_pos, self.y_pos))
        self.text_rect = self.text.get_rect(center=(self.x_pos, self.y_pos))

    def update(self, screen):
        if self.image is not None:
            screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.text, self.text_rect)

    def checkForInput(self, position):
        if position[0] in range(self.rect.left, self.rect.right) and position[1] in range(self.rect.top, self.rect.bottom):
            return True
        return False

    def changeColor(self, position):
        if position[0] in range(self.rect.left, self.rect.right) and position[1] in range(self.rect.top, self.rect.bottom):
            self.image = self.hovering_image
            if pygame.mixer.Sound.get_num_channels(splat) < 1 and self.image:
                pygame.mixer.Sound.play(splat)
        else:
            self.image == self.image2
```

And I use this in the main loop of the menu:

```
for button in [PLAY_BUTTON, RANKING_BUTTON, OPTIONS_BUTTON, QUIT_BUTTON]:
    button.changeColor(MENU_MOUSE_POS)
    button.update(win)
```

The function that makes the sound is changeColor.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain the specific problem(s)/error(s) this code has? All you've done so far is tell us what the code is supposed to do. What's the question? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can check where your mouse is and then play a sound. Since you don't want the sound to play in loop, we will have a variable called played, that will know if the sound was played or not:

```
played = False
sound = pygame.mixer.sound('sound.mp3')
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    if x <= pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] <= width and y <= pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] <= height: #where x, y are the left-top corner of the button and width and height are the sizes of the button
        sound.play(0)
        played = True
    else:
        played = False
```